# Bundle EULA with setup - using WiX 3.10 (with VS 2015 & Add in Express 8.1.4350)

Tags: wix, visual-studio-2015, setup-project, eula, addin-express

I just need to add EULA (End User License Agreement) to my WiX setup. I have done the same thing using WiX 3.8 (with VS 2012) more than 10 times, but I can’t make the same using 3.10 (with VS 2015).

**What I have tried?**

I added the same old code in the .wxs file. See below;

```
<WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf" Value="EULA.rtf" />
```

It gives me this error in compile time.

“A string was provided with characters that are not available in the specified database code page '1252'. Either change these characters to ones that exist in the database's code page, or update the database's code page by modifying one of the following attributes: Product/@Codepage, Module/@Codepage, Patch/@Codepage, PatchCreation/@Codepage, or WixLocalization/@Codepage.  Blackbaud CRMSetup2 C:\build\work\eca3d12b\wix3\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\LicenseAgreementDlg.wxs”

I went through WiX documentation and could not find something interesting either. (Please note that I don’t have a requirement for implementing multiple cultures/ localization)

Any ideas please??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your RTF document is corrupted, Can you try again with a simple RTF document ?